# How to set TAborder in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem i make a wpf application its running well.but i want to set the tab order of each my form but i don't get any taborder in Vs2008 express edition how can i solve this is any body help me 
thanks in advance 
shashank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the TabIndex work on Image control set the following property

```
<Image Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Source="img.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TabIndex property to set the tab order.

Comment: but Image control doesn't have tab index and i want to set the tab order on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ComboBox KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"/>
```

Comment: but its not working on image control i m taking some images instead of button i wan to fix the tab order on it